# In a GLMM model 2 predictors (covariates) correlate positively but affect the response with opposite relationships. Is it possibile?

Tags: correlation, glmm, predictor, variance-inflation-factor

I am checking the results of my GLMM model

```
full = glmmTMB(Shannon ~ z.maternalGC.earlygest +
         z.maternalGC.mean.lact + 
         z.GCsample +
         sex + age_cat + season + group + 
         (1|individual_id),
         data = xdata.field)
```

the response is a microbial diversity measure from fecal samples and the z-transformed covariates are measures of stress. Now, from previous analyses I know that 2 covariates: `z.maternalGC.earlygest` and `z.GCsample` correlate positively and I can also easily see it when I just plot the 2 covariates from the same database, one against each other.

```
ggplot(xdata.field, aes(x=z.maternalGC_earlygest, y=z.GCsample)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="glm" , color="red", fill="#69b3a2", se=TRUE)
```

So far everything makes sense. However, when I run `summary(full)` and check the results of my GLMM `z.maternalGC.earlygest` has a positive effect while `z.GCsample` has a negative one. How is it possible that 2 covariates positively correlated have an opposite effect on my response? Does it make sense statistically speaking? Could somebody explain to me if that's normal and how is it possible? I mean, I ran that correlation and I see a positive effect so I am expecting that if one variable has an effect, the other one may have no effect or the same direction effect, not the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(2021)
N <- 1000
mu <- c(0, 0)
S <- matrix(c(1, 0.9, 0.9, 1), 2, 2)
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, mu, S)
x1 <- X[, 1]
x2 <- X[, 2]
e <- rnorm(N)
y_hat <- 1 + x1 - x2
y <- y_hat + e
L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(L)
cor(x1, x2)
```

Here, the `x1` and `x2` variables have a strong *positive* correlation over $0.9$, yet their regression coefficients have opposite signs.

Just because increases in `x1` tend to correspond to increases in `x2` does not mean that both must correspond to increases in `y`. If you did a controlled study where you forced `x1` to be constant while you varied `x2`, you would find `y` to change about $-1$ units for every one-unit change in `x2`.

Comment: For those unable or unwilling to run the code, would you mind displaying the key parts of the output you are relying on?